# Search column and store inside variable using grep or awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Here is a `file.txt` that has the following data:

```
|ip: 2607:5300:0061:0eda:0000:0000:0000:0000 |abuse_score: 80 |isp: OVH Hosting Inc. |usage_type: Data Center/Web Hosting/Transit |domain: ovh.com |country_name: Canada |country_code: CA |total_report: 27 |distinct_report: 14 |last_report: 2020-10-31T16:01:49+00:00 |time: Sun Nov  1 01:49:53 +08 2020
|ip: 2001:0000:1234:0000:0000:C1C0:ABCD:0876 |abuse_score: 19 |isp: Teredo RFC4380 |usage_type: Reserved |domain: can.com |country_name: United States of America |country_code: USA |total_report: 2 |distinct_report: 0 |last_report: Unknown |time: Sun Nov  1 01:54:28 +08 2020
|ip: 1.1.1.1 |abuse_score: 6 |isp: Teredo RFC4380 |usage_type: Search Engine Spider |domain: gooday.com |country_name: China |country_code: CN |total_report: 0 |distinct_report: 6 |last_report: Unknown |time: Sun Nov  1 01:54:28 +08 2020
|ip: 1.1.1.11 |abuse_score: 7 |isp: Teredo RFC4380 |usage_type: Hacking |domain: wwww.com |country_name: Rusia |country_code: RU |total_report: 3 |distinct_report: 4 |last_report: Sun Nov  1 01:54:28 +08 2020 |time: Sun Nov  1 01:54:28 +08 2020
|ip: 1.1.1.111 |abuse_score: 8 |isp: Teredo RFC4380 |usage_type: Gaming |domain: whyme.com |country_name: Rusia |country_code: RU |total_report: 3 |distinct_report: 8 |last_report: Unknown |time: Sun Nov  1 01:54:28 +08 2020
|ip: 1.1.1.15 |abuse_score: 90 |isp: Teredo RFC4380 |usage_type: IPS |domain: youknowthat.com |country_name: Rusia |country_code: RU |total_report: 100 |distinct_report: 99 |last_report: Sun Nov  1 01:54:28 +08 2020 |time: Sun Nov  1 01:54:28 +08 2020
|ip: 1.1.1.153 |abuse_score: 19 |isp: Teredo RFC4380 |usage_type: Commercial |domain: mynic.com |country_name: Malaysia |country_code: MY |total_report: 8 |distinct_report: 12 |last_report: Unknown |time: Sun Nov  1 01:54:28 +08 2020
```

So, I need to assign each value after `|name:` into variable for example to get the `ip`, `abuse_score` value, this is what I did:

```
ip=$(awk '{ print $2 }') # ip is perfectly assigned
abuse_score=$(awk '{ print $4}') # abuse_score is perfectly assigned
```

But then, to get the other one like `isp` (which has string that might contain one or more spaces), I could not use the above code because it will only return one word. The `ip` and `abuse_score` will never have space. For example to assign `isp` for the first record from the text file, if I use this

```
isp=$(awk '{ print $6 }')
```

This will only assign `isp=OVH`.

The value of `isp` should be assigned as `OVH Hosting Inc.`

How to deal this data that has spaces and assign each of this data into separate variable easily ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this **generic solution** using `awk`:

```sh
cat srch.awk
BEGIN{ FS = "[[:blank:]]*[|]" }
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
      if (match($i, /^[_[:alnum:]]+: /) && substr($i, 1, RLENGTH-2) == fld) {
          print ( substr($i, RLENGTH+1) )
          next
      }
   }
}
```

Then use it as:

```sh
awk -v fld='isp' -f srch.awk file.txt

OVH Hosting Inc.
Teredo RFC4380
Teredo RFC4380
Teredo RFC4380
Teredo RFC4380
Teredo RFC4380
Teredo RFC4380
```

Or else:

```
awk -v fld='usage_type' -f srch.awk file.txt

Data Center/Web Hosting/Transit
Reserved
Search Engine Spider
Hacking
Gaming
IPS
Commercial
```

Comment: I'm testing this solution. Upvoted for a great solution

Comment: This is a very good solution because the code can be reused

Comment: May I know if this has better performance compared to answer given by @Gordon Davisson ? Not sure how can I test this.

Comment: I think before benchmarking you need to compare functionality as well. For ex. this will allow you to pass any field name and get all values. IMHO Gordon's answer will require some change (e.g. finding column position in awk)

Comment: Thank you, tested this solution with several random data and it's working. This solution is very neat.

Comment: Funny, it fails on mawk 1.3.3 (Debian default) but works on mawks 1.3.4(.20200120) and 1.9.9.6 and the rest of awks I tried it on.

Comment: Hmm may be that mawk is broken. I have only tested it on BSD and gnu awk versions and it worked fine on both.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't like the character classes `[:...:]`

Comment: That is bracket expression supported in all Unix tools like sed, awk, grep, tr etc

Answer (score 3):

How about using `sed` to isolate the field (using "|" as a delimiter):

```
isp=$(sed -E 's/^.*\|isp: ([^|]*)( \|.*)?$/\1/' file.txt)
```

One possible problem with this is that if a line doesn't match it'll leave the entire line in, rather than giving a blank result. Depending on the setup, you could use sed's `-n` option and the `p` modifier on the replacement:

```
sed -nE 's/^.*\|isp: ([^|]*)( \|.*)?$/\1/p'
```

... which will print nothing if there's no match. But then if you process the entire file, non-matching lines will vanish (rather than becoming blank). Depending on how you're using it, this might need fixing.

Alternately, if you like `awk` and the isp will always be the third "|"-delimited field (fourth if you count the "|" at the beginning):

```
awk -F'|' '{sub("^isp: ", "", $4); print $4}'
```

Comment: I wish to upvote this answer but I couldn't do it with permission. Do you think I should modify the data? Ignore the `|name:` field and replace with another simpler field like `,`? Because this data was generated from another report that can also be modified by other team. Then that would be easier right ? What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The `sed` command doesn't modify the original file, it just prints extracted data from it. Are you saying the other team might change what fields are printed or their order? BTW, even if you don't have the karma to upvote, if the answer solves the problem you can select it as the "accepted" answer.

Comment: BTW, one confusion I think we're having is that our `sed` and `awk` commands don't have a data source provided. Depending on how you're processing the data, you'd either run the whole file through at once (e.g. `var=$(awk '{print $whatever}' file.txt)`) to get *all* of the values for that field, or you'd process a single line at a time with e.g. `var=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $whatever}'`)` to get the value from that line. In either case, the `sed` command I gave would work essentially like `awk`.

Comment: I mean the sample records given above were generated from another script that was created by another team. Do you think removing `|optional_field:` field for each column is easier to maintain and we replace it with only comma separater for each field `,` ? Actually I like the last solution that just appear (trying to avoid sed). Let me test it.

Comment: Switching to a CSV (comma-separated-values) format might be more widely compatible (there are lots of CSV-processing tools out there), but I think either format would work for what you seem to be doing.

Comment: The solution you have given is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: I think `sed` solution would need to be `sed -nE 's/^.*\|time: ([^|]*)( \|.*){0,1}$/\1/p' file.txt` to make it work for last field.

Comment: @anubhava Good point, although I prefer `?` to `{0,1}` (when in extended regex mode). I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. We have an `awk` variable named `search` just give your string in it and it will look for it in lines and print the matched part accordingly.

```
awk -v search="isp" '
match($0,search ":[^|]*"){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/[^:]*: +/,"",val)
  print val
  val=""
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v search="isp" '             ##Starting awk program and setting variable search isp here.
match($0,search ":[^|]*"){        ##Using match function to look for regexp(from search variable value colon till pipe match everything).
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)   ##Creating val which has sub string of matched regex.
  sub(/[^:]*: +/,"",val)          ##Substituting everything till colon with NULL in val.
  print val                       ##Printing variable vale here.
  val=""                          ##Nullify val here.
}' Input_file                     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Adding more generic solution, where if anyone wants to search multiple ids in a single `awk` we could do it. Just provide all strings which you need to search inside variable `search` with `,`(comma) delimiter and we will get all those matches.

```
awk -v search="isp,usage_type" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(search,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    valCheck[arr[i]]
  }
}
{
  for(key in valCheck){
    match($0,key ":[^|]*")
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    sub(/[^:]*: +/,"",val)
    valPrint[key]=(valPrint[key]?valPrint[key] ORS:"")val
    val=""
  }
}
END{
  for(key in valPrint){
    print "Printing values for " key "....." ORS valPrint[key]
  }
}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple Perl

```
$ perl -lne ' /isp:\s*([^|]+)/ and print $1 ' azimah.txt
OVH Hosting Inc.
Teredo RFC4380
Teredo RFC4380
Teredo RFC4380
Teredo RFC4380
Teredo RFC4380
Teredo RFC4380
$
```

Comment: nice solution with oneline perl.

Comment: how can i put variable for isp ? example field="isp" | `perl -lne ' /${field}:\s*([^|]+)/ and print $1 ' azimah.txt` . doesnt seems to work